# Can I apply for a standard Visitor Visa after my ICT visa expires?

Tags: visas, uk

Currently I am on an ICT LT visa and it is going to expire by end of April. I need to go back to my home country for a 1 year cooling off period. My family will stay in the UK as my spouse is on a General Tier 2 visa (I can't apply for General tier 2 dependent visa due to some other reasons).

Once I reach my home country, can I apply for a standard visitor visa (with 6 months validity) so that I can come and visit my family during the holidays? I can provide letters from my employer and property documents to show I will return home.